# Regex101: Check if a floating point number (e.g. 3.14159) is in a valid format.(Question 11)

Tags: javascript, regex

This is question 11 from the regex101 quiz

I have been trying to figure out a solution to solve the test case below from failing.
Can someone help with this?

> Test 60/89: Just a dot is not a valid floating number.

I am using the regex below.

`/^[+-]?\d*([.,]\d*)?([Ee][+-]?\d+)?$/g`

Comment: You should include all examples of what valid floating point numbers are here.

Comment: https://regex101.com/quiz/11
If you could refer to this link, that will make things much easier because there are 89 test cases to this problem.

Comment: @gauravsabharwal are you expecting readers to do a test to see examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^[-+]?(\d+[,.]|\d*[.,]?\d+)(e[-+]?\d+)?$/i
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `(\d+[,.]|\d*[.,]?\d+)` - either one or more digits, then `,` or `., or zero or more digits, an optional` .`or`,` and then one or more digits
- `(e[-+]?\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of `e`, then an optional `-` or `+` and then one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.